# Wordpress: Active theme not showing in 'Themes' folder

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a wp site locally, using XAMPP. However, the active theme I'm using (OceanWP) is not showing up in the wp-content\themes folder where it is supposed to be. I can see 3 other themes that are inactive. When looking at the src in in Chrome, i can see that the theme I'm using is actually there, but, as I said, when I navigate there in file explorer it is not visible. Have anyone experienced this before?

I need to access that folder to get to the functions.php file in my theme in order to make some adjustments. Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, saw it today for the first time. Was driving me nuts. The solution that worked for me was to try to install the theme again from its zip file (using upload theme button) It failed with the message "Destination folder already exists." followed by the folder name. 
This did not have the same parent as the standard twentytwenty folder. In my case the parent was in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/